# jquery.validate.unobtrusive Not Working with Firefox/Chrome

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, unobtrusive-validation

For MVC 3.0 -Client Validation on dynamic content is works fine in IE with below line.

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse()
```

But this is not the case when firefox / chrome. Please suggest any workaround.

Comment: What version of `IE` and `JQuery Validation` are you using?

Comment: i'm using IE 8, and Jquery 1.5.1

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to be passing any argument to the parse function. You need to pass it a selector that will contain all the new elements that were added with AJAX. In the worst case:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(document);
```

But it would be better to specify a container:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse('form');
```

or:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#someContainer');
```

Also there's a gotcha. If you don't refresh the `<form>` element that contains the newly added elements with AJAX, i.e. the form tag is not part of the partial, you will need to first remove previous validation rules that were associated with this form or the `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse` method won't do anything:

```
$('form').removeData('validator');
$('form').removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse('form');
```